Deploying Vue/Vite project to Firebase via Bitbucket pipelines
I am trying to setup a Bitbucket Pipeline for my Vue project to Firebase but am getting this error but am able to deploy locally from my terminal
Could not load dependency vite in ./, have you run `npm install`?
[2024-08-23T14:49:59.128Z] Error: Cannot find module 'vite'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/utils.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/controller.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/commandUtils.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/database-get.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js

Below is my yml file
image: node

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        script:
          - npm install && npm run build
        artifacts:
          - dist/**

    - step:
        name: Deploy to Firebase
        deployment: dev
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:5.1.1
            variables:
              FIREBASE_TOKEN: $FIREBASE_TOKEN
              PROJECT_ID: $FIREBASE_PROJECT
              MESSAGE: 'Deploying to Dev'
              DEBUG: 'true'
              FIREBASE_CLI_EXPERIMENTS: webframeworks
              EXTRA_ARGS: '--only hosting'

